# Bound on sequence of functions that have a pointwise limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of real-valued functions such that $f_n(t) \to 0$ as $t \to 0$ for each $n$.

Does it follow that for all $n$ big enough, we have
$$f_n(t) \leq 1$$
and this holds whenever $t \in [0,T]$ for some $T>0$ independent of $n$?

Or do I need some uniform convergence at $t=0$ to get this?

Answer (score 0):

From your specification, no. You only get:

$\forall n \in \mathbb N$, and $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta_{n, \epsilon} > 0$, s.t. $|f_n(t)| < \epsilon$, whenever $|t| < \delta_{n,\epsilon}$